# How to project a texture from one object to another?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have an object with a texture.
I'm putting another object just over it like shown here. The goal is to add a road to a terrain and have the road edge smoothly blend in with the terrain texturing.

[image]

From this image, it can be seen that the road and its edge are overlaid on the terrain mesh.

[image]

Using cycles, I'd like to be have a shader that projects the terrain texture up to the road bed, along the z-axis, so the edge of the added texture looks like part of the original terrain.

---

The preference is to do this without baking textures.